# where an environment variable is defined?

Tags: linux

Is there a easy way in Linux(Redhat) to find out in which script an environment variable is defined? for example, I would like to know where is LS_COLORS defined.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: I would just `grep` for `LS_COLORS`, both in `/etc/` and in dot-files in your `$HOME`

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
set -x
```

at the top of your `.profile` (or `.bash_profile` if that's what you use). This will cause all the commands to be displayed as they're executed. You should be able to see where it assigns `LS_COLORS`, then search back for the most recent `source` or `.` command to get the script name.

Answer (score -1):

In the command prompt type:

```
set
```

This will display all environment variables. If you want just **LS_COLORS** you can type:

```
echo "$LS_COLORS"
```

As Barmar mentioned you can permanently have those variables set in the .profile/.bash_profile or set them in you terminal for that session.